# How to do Password validation in react js using joi schema?

Tags: reactjs, validation, schema, joi

I want to validate the password rules as:
Password should be 8 characters long, should have 1 upper case and 1 lower case, 1 number and 1 special character.

```
password: new passwordComplexity({
      min: 8,
      max: 25,
      lowerCase: 1,
      upperCase: 1,
      numeric: 1,
      symbol: 1,
    }),
password: Joi.string()
  .min(8)
  .max(25)
  .required()
  .label("Password")
  .error((errors) => {
    errors.forEach((err) => {
      switch (err.type) {
        case "any.empty":
          err.message = passwordRequired;
          break;

        case "string.min":
          err.message = passwordInvalid;
          break;

        case "string.max":
          err.message = passwordInvalidMax;
          break;

        default:
      }
    });
    return errors;
  }),
```

I tried these but passwordComplexity I guess works only with node js. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for the help. However, I found a solution to this as:

```
password: Joi.string()
      .min(8)
      .max(25)
      .regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/, 
      'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try to use Regex and pass in to the pattern

```
Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$'))
```

For more info on how to user Regex: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

```js
Joi.string()
.regex(/[ -~]*[a-z][ -~]*/) // at least 1 lower-case
.regex(/[ -~]*[A-Z][ -~]*/) // at least 1 upper-case
.regex(/[ -~]*(?=[ -~])[^0-9a-zA-Z][ -~]*/) // basically: [ -~] && [^0-9a-zA-Z], at least 1 special character
.regex(/[ -~]*[0-9][ -~]*/) // at least 1 number
.min(4)
.required()
```

What is `[ -~]`? *(Note the beginning **space**)*

It denotes ASCII printable characters [from \x20 to \x7E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), which
can represents all possible input for a password, include numbers, letters and symbols, except those control characters.

If you don't understand line 4, you can search for Lookahead Assertion and Character Class Intersection (This one is for java, not javascript).