# Joi-browser Validation Password

Tags: reactjs, validation, passwords, joi

I need to crate paswword in these conditions:

- At least 4 numbers
- At least 1 lower-case letter
- At least 1 capital letter
- At least 1 special sign
- At least 8 characters

I wrote this code in joi browser:

```
   password: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]+4)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/)
      .required()
      .min(8),
```

But from some reason it doesn't work, psrt of the passwords are working but part ot them are not

For exmple:
Josh1995* - not working
Ja1234** - are working

Why is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```js
Joi.string()
.regex(/[ -~]*[a-z][ -~]*/) // at least 1 lower-case
.regex(/[ -~]*[A-Z][ -~]*/) // at least 1 upper-case
.regex(/[ -~]*(?=[ -~])[^0-9a-zA-Z][ -~]*/) // basically: [ -~] && [^0-9a-zA-Z]
.min(4)
.required()
```

- If you don't understand `[ -~]`, [this is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838328/12924996).
- If you don't understand line 4, you can search for `Lookahead Assertion` and `Character Class Intersection` (This one is for java, not javascript).